# Tried various possibilities to solve ClassCastException : EditText cannot be cast to ViewGroup

Tags: android, android-edittext, classcastexception, viewgroup

I have tried various possibilities to get rid of the ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup. I have tried to clean the project, changed a bit of layout, adjusted their widths and heights, but haven't been able to solve it yet. The moment I touch the Button I get this exception. Please help me.

Here is the XML layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView android:id="@id/top_bar_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/top_bar" android:contentDescription="@string/content" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/txt_recipients"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp" android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/text_recipients" android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<ImageButton android:id="@id/btn_back"
    android:layout_width="80dp" android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content" android:onClick="finishActivity"
    android:paddingTop="6dp" android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/Rlayout_recipients"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/top_bar_view" android:background="@drawable/bg">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_three"
        android:layout_width="400dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_two" android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_two"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp" android:background="@drawable/fill_rece"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_one" android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fill_rece" android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="text" />

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/btn_rec_add"
        android:layout_width="25dp" android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_rec_one"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/content" android:src="@drawable/icon_add" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edt_rec_two" android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_rec_one"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_rec_add" android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fill_rece" android:contentDescription="@string/content"
        android:ems="10" android:inputType="text">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public class RecipientsActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton btn_rec_add;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipients);       
    addListenerForButtons();
}

private void addListenerForButtons() {
    btn_rec_add = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_rec_add);
    btn_rec_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent rec_addr_Intent = new Intent(RecipientsActivity.this,RecipientAddressActivity.class);
            startActivity(rec_addr_Intent);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Please share your java class also !!

Comment: `EditText` is not a subclass of `ViewGroup`, that way you can't cast it to it. Although you haven't shared your code with us, my guess is, that you have a line like this in your `Button`'s `onClick` listener: `EditText et = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.edt_rec_xxx);`

Comment: @Jigar Pandya Sorry for the delay in my response. I have added Java code above. Thanks

Comment: @PsHegger Thanks for your response. I haven't used EditText yet in my Java Code. I have added the java code above. Kindly, have a look

Answer (score 0):

This is because, `EditText` is not a subclass of `ViewGroup` but is of `View`. When is-a test fails for a particular class then `ClassCastException` is thrown at the runtime.

Comment: Can you point out in the code where to change to get rid of that exception. I have been struggling with it for quite some time.

Comment: there is no problem in the `RecipientsActivity` class as you are not using `EditText` in here but this issue can be in `RecipientAddressActivity` as you've mentioned in one of your comments that this exception gets thrown when you click on the button. All you are doing is starting a new `Activity` so the issue must be present there..

Comment: @d3mOli5h3r Thanks a lot for pointing out. You were right. The problem is indeed in RecipientAddressActivity.